# How to automate publishing multiple ASP.NET web applications and backup the previous published folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

Our application is a 3 tier one. It has 3 ASP.NET web applications talking to each other via WCF and Webservices. We use TFS to version control. We have several test environments setuped with different configs. At the moment to publish the aplication we get latest version from the TFS, right-click each project,  select publish, select pubishing profile and click publish to publish. We do this to all 3 projects. Besides we need to backup previous builds before publishing. How can we automate this process?

Comment: How many different environments do you publish to for each project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  The most common route is to use automate your builds using MSBuild:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Using MSBuild you can automate building each project, backing up your previous builds, and deploy the application via web deploy:

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

Unless you're doing anything crazy, you shouldn't have much trouble.  If you're looking for something a little easier to use, I've had great luck with using a standalone build server and Automated Build Studio:

http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/build-management/

There's a lot of information out there on the topic; let me know if you have any questions.  Good luck!